# How to use classes from another target for tests in XCTest

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I use Xcode 6.1 to create a new project, and it comes with a Tests target. I am trying to use the classes defined in another demo target in the same project for tests. But how do I accomplish this (besides setting the class's target membership to both demo and tests targets)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the source file in question and press <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to see the file inspector, and then select the appropriate targets in the "Target membership" section. Or, go to the target setting, click on "Build Phases" tab and add it to the "Compile Sources" section.

Comment: I mentioned except add it to target membership. Is there another way?

Comment: While I search on network. I found out you can create a framework to accomplish this. Can you suggest a tutorial about that?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with WWDC 2014 video [Building Modern Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=416). By the way, you still have to add the framework to your target.